# How to verify if a send keys statement has actually worked?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am automating my app using selenium with Ruby.

Is there any way to verify if send_keys :tabs has worked,the key press event has been executed?

Comment: Does the `send_keys` action cause any determinable change in the application under test?  If so, then I'd try to assert/verify the change.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in application as a result of `send_keys :tabs` is a way to check. If your problem is to debug and if you haven't tried [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry#runtime-invocation) give it a shot. Install gem, `require 'pry'` in ur script and call `binding.pry` from where u want control, it gives u control similar to irb with current script context.

Comment: Thanks ! I just wanted to know if there is any other way to determine the key press event have been executed other than changes in the application.

Comment: @user2993178, debugger in firefox has events pane which lists all DOM events that currently have listeners bound from your code. you can add sleep before ur send_keys open debugger and watch on keypress/keydown  events..[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/UI_Tour#Events_pane] If I may ask, what is are planning to achieve / can you add more details ??

Comment: The automation framework in which i execute my tests sometimes doesnt execute the key press events.so,i am looking for ways to add extra layer of check s in my tests.Thanks